# Adding local video to peer connection

Tags: swift, webrtc

I am building an IOS swift application where I have some difficulties to append an video stream to the mediaStream.

I use this library: https://github.com/Anakros/WebRTC everything works like a charm. Except the video stream. I don't know how to bind the video stream to the media stream. The code:

```
var mediaStream: RTCMediaStream!
@IBOutlet weak var localFrame: UIView!
var peerConnectionFactory = RTCPeerConnectionFactory()
var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()
let g = peerConnectionFactory.avFoundationVideoSource(with: nil);
previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: g.captureSession)
previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
localFrame.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

previewLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.localFrame.frame.width / 2, y: self.localFrame.frame.height / 2)
previewLayer.bounds = localFrame.frame

localVideoTrack = peerConnectionFactory.videoTrack(with: g, trackId: VIDEO_TRACK_IDD)
mediaStream.addVideoTrack(localVideoTrack)

mediaStream = peerConnectionFactory.mediaStream(withStreamId: LOCAL_MEDIA_STREAM_IDD)
mediaStream.addVideoTrack(localVideoTrack)
```

It crashes on this row: mediaStream.addVideoTrack(localVideoTrack) with the following error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` I don't know what I'm doing wrong because all types are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see duplicate line for

```
mediaStream.addVideoTrack(localVideoTrack)
```

You need to create media stream before adding track to it. So, comment fist line and try.